# Cant create h2 table via docker (sprint boot app)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jpa, h2

Im bulding a rest api using spring boot.

I tried to create table in h2 db in various ways like using data.sql or schema.sql, but none of them actually create the tables so I wrote this code:
[image]

This code works perfectly when I run it via ide(intelij).

But when I try to run it using java "-jar target/projectName.jar" it doesn't create the table.

In addition, when I pack and run the app from docker the table doesn't being created.
Is someone know what I'm doing wrong?

application. properties:
[image]

Dockerfile:
[image]

Comment: Is the h2 jar present in your projectName.jar? I mean when you package your  projectName.jar, is h2 included in it?

Comment: Also please consider posting actual code instead of images.

Comment: @akuma8 
How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.RC1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) to see how to make db initialization work.
You can create a sql file as `src/main/resources/schema-h2.sql` and have application properties like

```
server.port=8090
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Property
`spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`
will help you initialize database with the content written in `schema-h2.sql` file

Please make sure that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` is always set to none to run db initialization script properly.